# How do I find the correct coordinates to align labels with barplot bars?

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I'm creating a graphic that has a few different graph elements, using `layout()` to define plotting regions. I have a separate region for labels that need to align to bars on a barplot in an adjacent plotting region.

I can take a guess at where to plot the labels so that they line up - but the number of these locations will vary so this is not an ideal solution.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
labs <- paste("Some text", letters[1:9])
datA <- table(sample(letters[1:9], size=200, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(c(0.1,0.2,0.3),3)))
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE), widths=c(1,2), heights=c(6,1))
plot.new()
text(x=1, y=seq(0.05,1.0,0.111), labels=labs, adj=1, cex=1.4)
barplot(datA, horiz=TRUE, las=1, axes=F, yaxt="n")
```

How can I find the correct values to plot the labels?

(I'm aware that it looks like this can be solved by just plotting the labels with the barplot - this is not a viable solution for what I'm doing).

Answer (score 1):

The output of `barplot` gives the heights so:

```
bp <- barplot(datA, horiz=TRUE, las=1, axes=F, yaxt="n")
text(0*bp, bp, labs, col = "blue", pos = 4)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm putting the labels into a separate plotting region, the values from barplot() don't give the correct location for the labels.

Comment: Well, just don't use a separate plotting region.

Comment: Don't call a new plot region, avoid to use `plot.new()`. Conversely, after assignment the plot to a variable, simply call the variable, in this case simple `bp`